# MySQL add prefix to field table-wide

Tags: mysql

Basically I just decided to switch my primary ID to a "source" field, as I will be importing stuff from multiple sources. Now I'd like to make it clear where things come from, as such I'd like to add a prefix to it, as to be `portalname:formerID`. I've tried

```
UPDATE pics SET source='nk:'+source WHERE 1=1
UPDATE pics SET source='nk:'+source WHERE faces > 0 (matches all records)
```

but every time phpMyAdmin returns `0 row(s) affected. ( Query took 0.0056 sec )`

Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use CONCAT() ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat ) to concatinate strings, not "+".

Comment: `UPDATE pics SET source=CONCAT('nk:',source) WHERE 1=1` worked as expected. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

you may try to omit the where clause altogether.

```
UPDATE pics SET source= concat('nk:',source )
```

or better yet, add a new column `'portal_name'` and populate that seperately.